# Same Exact Button on Differrent Scene Using Same Function Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, scene

I have this code on 'MainMenu' Scene:

```
Home_IconB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Home);
function Home(e) {
gotoAndPlay(186,"MainMenu");
}
```

and this code on 'ViewMerchandise1' Scene:

```
Home_IconB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Home);
```

I have the same exact button on those two scenes. But I can't use the same function that I've wrote on the 'MainMenu' Scene. The button on 'ViewMerchandise1' Scene just won't work.

Comment: Try giving the second button a different **instance name**. You are passing the same type of event to the function so that shouldn't be a problem. I.E ViewMerchandise1 scene event listener will be `Home_IconB1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Home);`

Comment: @adaam is that means I have to make a different name for the button for each scene?

Comment: Yes pretty much. Try it and see.

Comment: @adaam Thanks for your help. I try to close my flash, and reopen it. And somehow it works. Thanks for your help anyway :)